# Error: TransformError Invaild call at line : require(image)

Tags: react-native

I want to show some pictures on the screen by reading JSON.
Here is my JSON code:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "First",
      "imgPath": "./src/assets/images/1.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Second",
      "imgPath": "./src/assets/images/2.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Third",
      "imgPath": "./src/assets/images/3.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Project tree

[image]

Here is my code:

```
var Images = require('ImageData');

class MainView extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={MainViewStyles.mainBoxStyle}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 50}}>MainView</Text>
                //call the method
                {this._renderImages()}
            </View>
        );
    }


     //read the json file
    _renderImages(){
        let renderedImages = [];
        let images = Images.data;
        for (let i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            let image = images[i];
            renderedImages.push(
                <Image source={require(image)} />
            );
        }
        return renderedImages;
    }

}
```

Running error

[image]

Here is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
```

The above is my project configuration information

How can I make my JSON file read successfully, and the picture is displayed on the screen successfully

Comment: What was an error ?  seems like it was an package issue

Comment: sorry,I uploaded the running error picture again.

Answer (score 0):

First, your All images are **static** and it resides in your local project. It was not coming from any API service. Assuming that you want to access the images locally you can do

```
import img1 from '../images/1.jpg';
```

You can access it like this

```
<Image source={img1} />
```

**Assumption # 2**

Everything was perfect and it coming form API then you need to do simply

```
     //read the json file
_renderImages(){
    let renderedImages = [];
    let images = Images.data;
    for (let i=0;i<images.length;i++){
        let image = images[i];
        renderedImages.push(
            <Image source={i.imgPath} />
        );
    }
    return renderedImages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.

```js
 var imagePath = arr[6];
        const test = require(imagePath);
        return (< Image source={test} style={{ width: 50, height: 60 }} />)
```